# Mahalanabois distance in python returns matrix instead of distance

Tags: python, numpy, math

This should be a simple question, either I am missing information, or I have mis-coded this.

I am trying to implement Mahalanabois distance in python which I am following from the formula in python.

My code is as follows:

```
a = np.array([[1, 3, 5]])
b = np.array([[4, 5, 6]])

X = np.empty((0,3), float)
X = np.vstack([X, [2,3,4]])
X = np.vstack([X, a])
X = np.vstack([X, b])

n = ((a-b).T)*(np.cov(X)**-1)*(a-b)
dist = np.sqrt(n)
```

dist returns a 3x3 array but should I not be expecting a single number representing the distance?

```
dist = array([[ 1.5       ,  1.73205081,  1.22474487],
       [ 1.73205081       ,  2.        ,  1.41421356],
       [ 1.22474487       ,  1.41421356,  1.        ]])
```

Wikipedia does not suggest (to me) that it should return a matrix.  Googling implementations of mahalanbois distance in python I have not found something to compare it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) you could see, that `a` and `b` are vectors but in your case they are arrays. So you need reverse transposing. And also there should be matrix multiplication. In numpy `*` means element-wise multiplication, for matrix you should use [`np.dot`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiI6aLqpqbLAhUpS5oKHdBGC8AQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy-1.10.0%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.dot.html&usg=AFQjCNEnXoVfDBC-t1LKiFa_iDAyWbA2fA&sig2=gRaQHs-fUoBuopOxN35wGw) function or `.dot` method of the `np.array`. For your case answer is:

```
n = (a-b).dot((np.cov(X)**-1).dot((a-b).T))
dist = np.sqrt(n)

In [54]: n
Out[54]: array([[ 25.]])

In [55]: dist
Out[55]: array([[ 5.]])
```

**EDIT**

As @roadrunner66 noticed you should use inverse matrix instead of inverse matrix of element. Usually `np.linalg.inv` works for that cases but for that you've got Singular Error and you need to use [`np.linalg.pinv`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html):

```
n = (a-b).dot((np.linalg.pinv(np.cov(X))).dot((a-b).T))
dist = np.sqrt(n)

In [90]: n
Out[90]: array([[ 1.77777778]])

In [91]: dist
Out[91]: array([[ 1.33333333]])
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be the matrix inverse `numpy.linalg.inv` rather than the point wise inverse?

Comment: @roadrunner66 off course it should. Missed that. Hovewer `np.linalg.inv(np.cov(X))` gives error `LinAlgError: Singular matrix` ..

Comment: Yes, the matrix used was possibly not well formed.